# How to to playback beyond the frame range

Tags: animation

I am trying to emulate a clock timekeeping using the geometry nodes, following a tutorial online; the timekeeping system itself works great. However, when I play the animation, the timeline plays the frame range I created (1440 frames, for 60 secs at 24 fps) and the minute pin resets itself instead of continuing counting forward. I can move beyond the frame range by scrubbing the play-head without a problem and everything works as expected.

Is it possible to playback beyond the frame range, so my clock driver will be able to tick time indefinitely rather than being limited by the frame range?

I am using the brand new Blender 3.1.0. Let me know if you need the BLEND file.

Comment: Answered on BA already: https://blenderartists.org/t/timeline-issue/1366800/2

Comment: if you provide your blend file - i will help you

Comment: Short answer is no, you can't playback outside of frame range. But that's not where the problem is... Maybe you should adapt your clock system instead?

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you for your answer. Please find a link to the file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KWH8iUooOwyQkViUkplpZW4QOkK9VMj2/view). The BA response points at creating as many frames as seconds I intend to include, which I can always do, but the guy in the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PWaBW5uJfE&t=570s) video plays the animation over the frame-range without an issue. Please help; this issue is ruining this beautiful project.